# VideoJS - how to set "controlsBelow" and "controlsHiding" options with Videojs 4

Tags: html, video, html5-video, video.js

With Video.js v4.3.0, how can I set the following options?
 - to locate a control bar below a video area
 - to show a control bar all the time (not to hide it even if the user is inactive)

This could be perform with the following script with Videojs v2 (and v3, not sure).

```
// this is an old method for Videojs v2 (and v3)
VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady({
             controlsBelow: true, 
             controlsHiding: false
       });
```

I try to do it with video-js.css modification. It does not work on mobile environment (on iPad, Android etc.), while it works fine on PC.

```
/* for locating a control bar below a video area */
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-control-bar {
  /* bottom: 0;    default value */
  bottom: -36px;
}

/* for not hiding a control bar */
.vjs-fade-out{
  /* visibility:hidden; default value */
  /* opacity:0;         default value */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me here.